Move table definitions between two SQL Server databases
On SQL Server Management Studio v 19.1 on database TEST I have more than 1000 tables, views and stored procedures.
I want to export the definitions and import them into database PROD.
Due to the large number of objects it is impossible to use "Generate scripts"
And I do not have access to all the SYS tables.

"Due to the large number of objects it is impossible to use "Generate scripts"" I've, personally, never had a problem with doing that, even for lots of objects. I hope you're not trying to put all the definitions into a single file, or open them in a single query window (that is madness). Though sounds like you really should have in place is source control and schema comparison software.

I only want to export definitions for one ot the schemas, but can't find a filter in "generate script".
And yes, I am moving the objects into source control

This feels like it only further cements by comment about source control and schema comparison software.

@PerGew the definitions are the scripts. 1000 tables aren't a lot. As for source control, SSDT or Azure Data Studio Database Projects not only extract the scripts from a database, they allow you to build, test them and create dacpacs from them that can be deployed to any database

@PerGew you can even create a dacpac directly from SSMS and import it into a database project. A dacpac is essentially a package containing all the scripts.

If you have Visual Studio available (2012 or later version), you can use SQL Schema Compare functionality. Select your Test as a source, Production as a target, optionally exclude object types you don't need to transfer (for me, it's usually permissions, role membership and users) and then you'll be able to deploy all the objects from source to destination.
If your VS instance doesn't have it, you'll need to install SQL Server Database Tools (SSDT). It's completely free.
